# Arabic Speech Recognition SDK for IOS

Tags: iphone, sdk, speech-recognition, arabic, speech-to-text

I need a Arabic speech to text API for IOS. I have gone through openears and iSpeech but they do not support Arabic or maybe i have missed it going through there documents.

Can someone guide me to some great SDK of Arabic Speech Recognition for IOS?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Why people are voting to close this question? What is bad in this question?

Comment: It is likely getting closed with the reason "Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it." - asking for recommendations doesn't have a specific answer and is a poor fit for Q&A format.  Try describe the problem you are having than the tool that you want to find.

Answer (score 0):

Google has a unofficial speech to text API you can use. Just send a FLAC encoded file to  https://www.google.com/speech-api/v1/recognize using a HTTP POST request and you will receive a reply with the interpreted text. Arabic is supported by this API.